# web3.js error ethjs-query gives out error in write contract functions

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, ethjs

**Hi I am getting error**

```
Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting inputs '[{"0":false}]' for method 'getTransactionReceipt' error: Error: [ethjs-format] hex string '[object Object]' must be an alphanumeric 66 utf8 byte hex (chars: a-fA-F) string, is 0 bytes
    at ethjs.min.js:11
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at i.getTransactionReceipt (ethjs.min.js:11)
    at i.e.<computed> [as getTransactionReceipt] (ethjs.min.js:11)
    at ethjs.min.js:11
```

**Im calling the smartcontract invest function :**

```
function invest()public payable onlyAmount() firstExist  returns(bool){    

//  balances[msg.sender]=msg.value;
 invested[msg.sender]+= msg.value;
 isInvested[msg.sender]=true;
 users[msg.sender].creationTime=now;
  commission=(msg.value.mul(10)).div(100);
 forCreators(commission);
emit Invest(msg.sender,msg.value);
 return true;
}
```

**Where As Im calling the function from web3.js like**

```
tokenContract.invest({
    from: user_address,
    gasLimit: web3.toHex(8000000),
    gasPrice: web3.toHex(web3.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
    value : web3.toHex( web3.toWei(0.25, 'ether'))

  })
  .then(txHash =>  eth.getTransactionSuccess(txHash)
      .then(receipt => {
        alert("Sigup Has been successful",receipt);
      })
  )
  .catch((err) => {
    alert("Error couldnot signUp");
    console.log(err);
  })
```

this error is showing on all write functions .. Read is working just fine. I have never encountered this error before. I tried deploying contract on Ropsten and Rinkeby same error.
And these contract functions are working just fine on etherscan and remix. 
In web3js Even Metamask doesnt appears for transactions. What might be the issue?

Comment: From the snippet of code it seems you are using ethjs instead of web3. The project ethjs hasn't been updated in a while, perhaps some new contructs are not supported yet. How `tokenContract` is created?

Comment: Hi I found a work around .. I used pure web3.js instead of eth.js which solved the issue

Comment: But Is ethjs not compatible with solidity 0.6.0 ? I did found a work around but I still couldnt figure out the root cause

Comment: From the error message some function is an hex string but it gets an object instead. It appears that some dependecy has changed signature.